another vs remaining
I used another because I learned in the comment section of this question that another should be used. But the freelancer who edited my text changed it to remaining. I think remaining is not correct because which one is the remaining one, 18% or 10%? Is remaining correct?

Nearly half (48%) of participants attend dance classes in private studios, while around a quarter (24%) take classes in school halls after school. Community halls and other locations, along with
college-based studios, account for another/the remaining 18% and 10%,
respectively.



I've downvoted the question because the answer depends on the sentence(s) before the one you've quoted.

You haven't provided a proper context. Unless immediately-preceding text explicitly specifies the 48% and 24% locations, you can't include either of another/the remaining. And since respectively has to apply equally to two (or more) preceding referents, it doesn't make sense for them both to be referred to as the remaining X%.

Sorry, everyone. I thought the first sentence is not important so I deleted it. Now, I've put it back. @FumbleFingers, that's exactly my concern. I think the percentages can't both be "the remaining percentage".

Well, I don't know exactly what you mean by the "freelancer" who edited my text, but if you're paying someone to edit your text, you should make sure they're not a half-wit! You don't even need to be a native Anglophone to see that the remaining percentage can't possibly make sense in a context involving respectively.

@FumbleFingers, according to your comment in another question, "another" should be used, right? It's almost impossible to find a freelancer who is good at dealing data. I've tried many. None of them is good. I can always spot problems.

according to your comment in another question, "another" should be used ??? Certainly nowhere on this page have I said anything like that, since imho it's better not to have anything at all in the exact cited context. Effectively for the same reason that your "freelancer" got tripped up! Numerate readers / audience will recognize that the total cited percentages add up to 100% (as will anyone if they match the pie-chart to the text! :), but although remaining doesn't work because of respectively, replacing it by another usually implies there's more to come.

The remaining is the correct choice here.

Another means "an additional item from a list".
The remaining means "every other item from the list, considered as a group."


He's retired now. He plays golf Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesdays. On another day he goes fishing if the weather is good.
He's retired now. He plays golf Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesdays. On the remaining days he goes fishing if the weather is good.

In the above examples, there are four non-golf days. Another refers to one of those four days. The remaining refers to all four of the days as a group.
So in your original example, there are two categories yet to be mentioned. "Another" will reference one of them; "the remaining" will reference the two of them together.

Thanks for the answer. Can I use 'the other' in my sentence?

No. The other would mean that there is only one last category to talk about. In your example there are two categories. (You could add them together: The other 28%.)

This is completely wrong. Respectively applies to both percentage figures, but they can't both be "the remaining percentage".

I take your point, but I don't think it's that simple. You are interpreting it as "the remaining percentages". I interpreted it as "the remaining [classes at] 18% and 10% respectively." I did this because the beginning of the sentence encourages us to group the last two categories together. Admittedly the paragraph could have been edited to resolve that ambiguity.


Community halls and other locations, along with college-based studios, account for another/the remaining 18% and 10%, respectively.

We should use another as remaining is used only if there’s just one figure left.

Community halls and other locations, [and] college-based studios account for [another] 18% and 10%, respectively.

Along with isn’t inappropriate as that would make college-based studios parenthetical.   I have used the
conjunction and instead.
If we want to use also the remaining or the other, we could say
Community halls and other locations account for another 18%; and college-based studios, the remaining (or the other) 10%.
